# Is this a common (nonlinear?) optimal control problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, control-theory

I have the following optimal control problem, which can be considered in a two period discrete time setting.  It has this generic form.

Let $w: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a given function, modeling terminal reward (in my example in mind, $w$ is negative, bounded, increasing, and concave).  At time $0$, the state of the system is known, and equal to $x$.  The controller can choose a control $t \in [0,\infty )$ such that the state of the system at time $1$ is $f(t,x,Z)$, where $Z$ is a standard random variable.  The cost of using strategy $t$ is $g(t,x)$.  The goal is to calculate

$\hat{w}(x) = \underset{t}{min} \ \left( g(t,x) + e^{-\lambda t} E [w(f(t,x,Z))] \right),$

and find the optimal $t$.  Is there a reference for explicit/computable solutions to this problem?  Subject to certain restrictions on w,f,g?

Comment: I would consider this to be a problem of minimizing an expected value (ie, $\min_t E[g(t,x) + e^{-\lambda t} w(f(t,x,Z))]$) rather than an optimal control problem. The solution techniques depend on how you evaluate the expectation.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit on your last sentence?

Comment: Are you using Monte Carlo or do you have a way of explicitly evaluating the expectation? If the former, you might look up work by Georg Pflug, if the latter, then this is an 'ordinary' optimization problem.

Comment: The expectation can't be computed analytically.  How can this be solved using monte carlo?  Is there another numeric method for solving it without probability?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can avoid probability if you have an expectation that cannot be computed explicitly?

Comment: Thanks copper.hat.  Do you have a reference for setting up Monte Carlo for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one I can recommend. I mentioned an author above (Pflug) who has a recent (relatively) book on stochastic optimization, but I have only glanced at his work. The bibliography might provide some clues.